# Magento transactionID and transactionAmount in javascript

Tags: javascript, magento

I am trying to implement a tradetracker-script to my checkout-success page, and I need to add **transactionID** and **transactionAmount** variables into a javascript. I guess {{var order.increment_id}} is correct for transactionID, but I just can't find the variable for transactionAmount (total order amount)

I run Magento CE 1.7.0.2

Could anyone please help. Thanks a lot.

-Espen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're taking the wrong approach here. From what I know, there are no javascript variables on the success-page that keep transactional data.

What I would do is: create a new child block of the order success page; then inspect the behaviour of the current success message, that clearly shows the order-ID. As soon as you have the order object in your PHP code, you can use this data in your javascript.

Here is a example using your javascript:

```
<?php $order = $this->getOrder(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ttConversionOptions = { type: 'sales', campaignID: '123456', productID: '123456', transactionID: '<?php echo $order->getIncrementId() ?>', transactionAmount: <?php echo $order->getGrandTotal(); ?>, quantity: '1', email: '', descrMerchant: '', descrAffiliate: '', currency: '' }
</script>
```

I guess you have to use a foreach loop with $order->getAllItems() for your productId-value, but I don't know tradetracker so well.

Comment: Thank you.. but in the instructions from Tradetracker I'm supposed to edit a javascript that shall be put on the order sucess page, this script should contain this info. The script looks like this:`<script type="text/javascript">
 var ttConversionOptions = {
  type: 'sales',
  campaignID: '123456',
  productID: '123456',
  transactionID: '{{var order.increment_id}}',
  transactionAmount: 'ORDER_AMOUNT',
  quantity: '1',
  email: '',
  descrMerchant: '',
  descrAffiliate: '',
  currency: ''`
...and so on....

Comment: Nearly @simonthesorcerer, but I had to change to <?php echo $this->__('%s', $this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId())) ?>   and  <?php echo $this->__('%s', $this->escapeHtml($this->getSubtotal())) ?>  to make it work. Thanks for helping.